# Is this the right way to compute gradients of two losses from two different NN's in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I have a NN defined in pytorch and I have created two instances of that net as `self.actor_critic_r1` and `self.actor_critic_r2`. I calculate the losses of each net i.e. `loss1` and `loss2` and I sum it up and calculate the grads in the following way,

```
loss_r1 = value_loss_r1 + action_loss_r1 - dist_entropy_r1 * args.entropy_coef
loss_r2 = value_loss_r2 + action_loss_r2 - dist_entropy_r2 * args.entropy_coef
self.optimizer_r1.zero_grad()
self.optimizer_r2.zero_grad()
loss = loss_r1 + loss_r2
loss.backward()
self.optimizer_r1.step()
self.optimizer_r2.step()
clip_grad_norm_(self.actor_critic_r1.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
clip_grad_norm_(self.actor_critic_r2.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
```

Alternatively, should I update the loss individually like this,

```
self.optimizer_r1.zero_grad()
(value_loss_r1 + action_loss_r1 - dist_entropy_r1 * args.entropy_coef).backward()
self.optimizer_r1.step()
clip_grad_norm_(self.actor_critic_r1.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
self.optimizer_r2.zero_grad()
(value_loss_r2 + action_loss_r2 - dist_entropy_r2 * args.entropy_coef).backward()
self.optimizer_r2.step()
clip_grad_norm_(self.actor_critic_r2.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
```

I am not sure if this the right approach to update a network with multiple loss please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the sum approach. If there is no interplay then the gradient of the 'wrong' loss will be zero for the 'wrong' optimizer anyway, and if there *is* interplay you likely want to optimize for that interplay.

Only if you know that there is interplay but you do not want to optimize for it should you use approach #2.

Comment: can you please explain it briefly and what do you specifically mean by "wrong loss" and "interplay"?

Comment: @MurtazaBasu Well `loss_r1` for `optimizer_r2` and vice versa would be 'wrong' and interplay would mean that `loss_r1` is actually dependent on `optimizer_r2` (and vice versa for `loss_r2` and `optimizer_r1`).

Comment: well in my case I don't want the grads of loss2 to have any influence on r1 and vice versa. I want the two nets to be updated independently without affecting each other but within the same infrastructure. Still, I need to use the sum method?

Comment: Okay I understood thank you. One last question I was using the individual approach until now and what I used notice is that 2nd net i.e. self.actor_critic_r2 used to improve gradually after each update whereas the net self.actor_critic_r1 never used to improve at all. Can this be because of the same reason?

Comment: @MurtazaBasu I don't know sorry.